# My CSS styles sheet will not display in Explorer but my page looks fine in GoogleChrome?

Tags: css

When opening my page in internet explorer it does not appear to see my css styles sheet. Yet when I open up my page in google chrome the page looks fine. Why can explorer not seem to see my styles sheet?

Comment: Could you provide your CSS and/or link elements from the page?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: perhaps your Server is not configured to send .css files as text/css (or you are using a wrong file extension). Some browsers are sensitive to mime types, some aren't.